# Removing an element from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` which contain 10 elements and a variable `int = 12`. Now I want to count how many elements are in `array` and if are less than `12` to start to count again from 0 and stop to index 2 and remove it, until I will have one element in my array. I tried the following:

```
int j = 12;
int l = 0;

// Here I check if j is less than array.size
while (j < array.size()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
        if (j == i + 1) {
            array.remove(i);
        }
    }
}
// Here is for j greater than array.size
while (array.size() != 1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
        l = j - array.size();
        if (l < array.size()) {
            array.remove(l);
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(array);
```

**UPDATE:**

```
MyArray = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int=12;
```

`MyArray` contain just `10` elements, but I want to delete the index with number `12`, as long as index `12` does not exist I should start to count again from zero, and the number `12` is at index `2`, That's why I should delete the index with number `2`. The second iteration `MyArray` will contain just `9` elements, and again `12-9=3`, I should delete the index with number `3`, until I will have just one element in `MyArray`

Comment: If you always remove the element at index 2, you will still have 2 elements left (index 0 and 1)

Comment: could you clarify what you are trying to achieve please? I'm not really able to understand what you're trying to do!

Comment: Could you give us a little bit of insight why it´s done this way, if you only want to have the element at index 1? It looks really confusing this way.

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: What about using "%"? `int indexToDel = i % array.size()` ? And I second Kevin: probably an x-y-Problem.

Comment: Well, actually it is impossible to remove the elements at `arrays.size() - j` and end with only having one element in your list. If `j = 12` and 10 elements are in the list, you will remove the 2nd (size = 9), 3rd (size = 8), 4th (size = 7), 5th (size = 6) and I will get a NPE at the next approach. I am still confused, tbh. ;)

Comment: The explanation is contradictory. How do you expect to ever reach one single element at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer to the updated question:

When you have a list of length 10 and you want to delete the "12th element" you can use the modulo operator:

```
ArrayList<...> someList = ...;
int toDelete = 12;

int deleteInRange = toDelete % someList.size();
someList.remove(deleteInRange);
```

The modulo operator will deliver the rest of the integerdivision 12 / 10 (`toDelete % someList.size()`)

You can use this code snippet in a loop in order to remove multiple elements.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping twice through the array to remove the last n elements until the length of the list equals j, you could simply use:

```
while (j < array.size()) { 
    array.remove(j - 1);
}
```

If you always want to remove index 2, you could do:

```
while (array.size() >= 3) { // otherwise you will get a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
     array.remove(2);
}
```

However, you will have two elements left in your ArrayList instead of 1 (at index 0 and 1). You cannot delete ìndex 2 at that point, because it is not a valid index any longer.

Thus, you could either remove index 0/1 afterwards or what I think you want to achieve:

```
while (array.size() >= 2) { // otherwise you will get a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
     array.remove(1);
}
```

Then only one element will remain in your list at index 0.

Edit: for the update of your question it is

```
int originalSize = array.size();
while (array.size() >= originalSize - j) { // otherwise you will get a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
     array.remove(originalSize - j);
}
```

However, you will always be left with `size - j` items in your list. You cannot remove index 3, for example, until you have only one element in your list.

Comment: Thank you for your help and perseverance I voted up your question, but is not what I want. Thank you one more time

Answer (score -1):

If you always want to remove index 2, you could do:

```
l = j - array.size();
```

Change this line as below:

```
int sum = 0;
sum = l - array.size();
if (sum > 0) {
    array.remove(sum);
} else {
    sum = array.size() - l;
    array.remove(sum);
}
```